# adding button to the cell in Jtable in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans6.7

How to add button in the cell of Jtable in netbeans???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add custom cell renderer, retarget some events from table and repaint cell when button state changes. It's evil, it's nasty, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows one way.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [Button Table Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) we will create a class that extends `JButton` and implements `TableCellRenderer`.

```
class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

  public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }
}
```

You then need to create a Cell Editor for the column also.

```
class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    return button;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
      // 
      // 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
      // System.out.println(label + ": Ouch!");
    }
    isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);
  }

  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }
}
```

We will then set an instance of the `ButtonRender` as the cell render for that column and an instance of ButtonEditor as the cell editor.

```
\\"Button" is the column name
table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(
    new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

The [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) in the link provided has the complete runnable example.

Comment: I tried this code and it displays button perfecly, but I am not able to click it, its not enabled or disabled, so do you know what is the issue with it? It looks like on the picture inside link you posted, but i cant click it...Thanks in advance!